# Separate string with format into array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to separate the values of a formatted string into an array. I have the string specifying format but cannot find a way to get the values of a formatted string given the format.

Here is the format string:

```
fmt=['%2i %2i %4i %2i %2i %2i %1i %11.7f %11.7f %12.5f %12.5f ' ...
'%5.2f %11.5f %5.2f %6.2f %2i %1i %9.5f %9.5f %3i\n'];
```

And here is an example of a formatted string that I'd like to separate:

```
 5 27 2015  2 21 17 0  32.3788833 -64.6799500      6.16800     -0.12000  5.53     0.36000  5.40   6.03  4 4 -99.99999 -99.99999 999
```

Is there any way of doing this? If not, in objective-c can I replace consecutive spaces with one space and then separate with one space?

Comment: Look into the `scanf` family of C functions.

Comment: If you need parsing and validation in one action you could try regular expression.

Comment: I'm sorry (I feel like I'm missing something obvious) but I don't completely understand your format string.  Could you give us an example of an input and output?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel The format string is only one line, although it appears here with the ... in the middle. The input is the second line, which is a string, and the output that I want is an array with each value in the string as a value in the array. The solution below by ankykush did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps,

```
NSString *yourStr = @"5 27 2015  2 21 17 0  32.3788833 -64.6799500      6.16800     -0.12000  5.53     0.36000  5.40   6.03  4 4 -99.99999 -99.99999 999 ";
NSPredicate *nonEmptyValue = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"];
NSArray *parts = [yourStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSArray *finalArr = [parts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:nonEmptyValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSString`'s `componentsSeparatedByString:` to convert your string into an `NSArray`.

Example:

```
NSString *string = @"5 27 2015 2 21 17 0 32.3788833 -64.6799500 6.16800 -0.12000 5.53 0.36000 5.40 6.03 4 4 -99.99999 -99.99999 999";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

P.S. *Make sure you clean your string from leading/trailing spaces and convert  multiple consecutive spaces into one single space character.*